# Javascript (JS) error initializing external defered js resources in inline js

Tags: javascript, flexslider

Having Error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function

When initializing flexslider in inline Js although loading the flexslider in defered external js

Here is the code

```
function parseJSAtOnload() {
        var moduleJsPath = "<?php echo BASE_URL.SHARED_ADDONPATH.'modules/fj/js/';?>";
        var links = [moduleJsPath + "flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js",moduleJsPath + "lazyload.min.js"],
        headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        linkElement, i;
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            linkElement = document.createElement("script");
            linkElement.src = links[i];
            headElement.appendChild(linkElement);
        }
    }
    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", parseJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", parseJSAtOnload);
    else window.onload = parseJSAtOnload;


window.onload = function(){
            $('.slider').flexslider({
                selector: ".form-group > .col-md-3",
                animation: "slide",
                animationLoop: false,
                itemWidth: 370,
                itemMargin: 5,
                maxItems:4,
                controlNav: false,
                slideshow: false,
                mousewheel:true
            });
}
```

Comment: Check the view source of the page, Dose "jquery.flexslider.js" file script is showing inside `<head>` area?

Comment: View source will not show the script as it has been defered in the function parseJSAtOnload()

Answer (score 0):

- Your code is correct, its working fine
- There is a possibility that your file `jquery.flexslider.js` is not on correct path.

> Solution : Apply `parseJSAtOnload()` function directly in **`<script>`**
>   tag.

You are receiving : `TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function` error:

[image]

Check this update:

```
function parseJSAtOnload() {
    var moduleJsPath = "<?php echo BASE_URL.SHARED_ADDONPATH.'modules/fj/js/';?>";
    var links = [moduleJsPath + "flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js",moduleJsPath + "lazyload.min.js"],
    headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
    linkElement, i;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        linkElement = document.createElement("script");
        linkElement.src = links[i];
        headElement.appendChild(linkElement);
    }
}

parseJSAtOnload();//function call to DOM

window.onload = function(){
    $('.slider').flexslider({
        selector: ".form-group > .col-md-3",
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        itemWidth: 370,
        itemMargin: 5,
        maxItems:4,
        controlNav: false,
        slideshow: false,
        mousewheel:true
    });
}
```

Comment: If i use parseJSAtOnload() directly so the objective of adding scripts in function and calling them on load will be obsolete.